# Angular - how to display only recently used items?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a list of persons and for each you can open a dialog and choose a property for it (let's say you can choose a city for the person).

I have a list of cities I get with a subscription, and they are all showed in the dialog.

What I want to add, is another section in the dialog, where I show only the last 5 cities selected for any person.

What's the best way to implement this? I was thinking about having an array, which I store up to 5 elements (how can you limit how many objects can be stored in an array? so when you add a new one when the limit is reached, the last item in the array will be pushed out?), so everytime when I click on a city for a different or same person, that city is stored in that array, and I simply display in the new recent section that array.

is it a good approach? 
thank you

Comment: `push` into the array, check the length, and if it's greater than 5, call `.pop` to remove one

Comment: thank you, I think that can work, is this a good approach? can't think of other ways but I m pretty new to angular

Comment: I would simply append a `lastUsed` to the object, and update it when the user interacts with it. To display, you simply have to filter on this property. The good side of that is that you can dynamically chose the period (last used this day, or this week, or this year ...)

Comment: @trichetriche could you provide me with an example? so if I add a new boolean: lastUsed to my Cities interface, and everything a city gets clicked, that boolean gets true, won't I have eventually all the lastUsed boolean set to true?

Comment: @AJ989 I wasn't talking about a boolean : see my example in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export interface RecentlyUsed {
  lastUsed: Date;
}

export interface City implements RecentlyUsed {
  lastUsed: Date;
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export class MyComponent {
  cities: City[];
  fiveLastUsedCities: [];

  get citiesUsedAfterToday() {
    const today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0);
    today.setMinutes(0);
    today.setSeconds(0);
    return this.citiesUsedAfterDate(today);
  }

  get citiesUsedThisHour() {
    return this.citiesUsedAfterDate(new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60));
  }

  constructor(public service: MyService) {}

  private citiesUsedAfterDate(d: Date) {
    return this.cities && this.cities.filter(city => city.lastUsed > d) || [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getCities().subscribe(cities => this.cities = cities);
  }

  pushCityInLastUsed(city: City) {
    const tmp = [...this.fiveLastUsedCities, city];
    this.fiveLastUsedCities = tmp.slice(-5);
  }
}
```

With this, you can now use your getters to get the cities used in the timespan you decide !

Comment: thank you very much for the effort! How should I tweak this if I'm not interested in retrieving the recent objects in a time frame? I just want to display the last 5 used
for a simple task like this, would your solution be overkill? and I could just save 5objects in an array and display those? thank you very much

Comment: My solution is indeed overkill. I edited my answer to add another function that can do what you want in two lines :) Last used city will be the last of the array

Comment: can I ask you what is this syntax: [...this.fiveLastUsedCities, city];    those 3 dots?

Comment: This is a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) : in the case of an array, it is like writing `const tmp = [this.fiveLastUsedCities[0], this.fiveLastUsedCities[1], this.fiveLastUsedCities[2], ..., city];`. it deconstructs objects and arrays, and avoid you the need to make loops over it.